# Callback passed to RemoteMediaPlayer.load(...).setResultCallback(...) does not fired after connection suspension/recovery

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I use `CastCompanionLibrary` and `Default Receiver`.

In order to know the result of video loading to cast device I set callback on `PendingResult.setResultCallback(...)` that is returned by `RemoteMediaPlayer.load(...)`. If during video loading connection was suspended and recovered callback never fired.

How determine the status of video loading (in progress/finished) after connection recovery?
How determine the result if loading finished?

Comment: This is late response but can help others. https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c7cb5a1ac38dc0001e4338f#L647

Answer (score 0):

You can always ask for the status and based on that, you can figure out what is going on: `Cast.CastApi.requestStatus(mApiClient)` or `RemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(..)` depending on your needs. Would that be all you need?

Comment: 1. Do I have to call `RemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(..)` after connection recovery and wait for result? Otherwise data will be outdated? Does RemoteMediaPlayer updates its status after connection recovery? Or it stays outdated permanently?
2. I can figure out the result of video loading based on `MediaStatus.getPlayerState()` and `MediaStatus.getMediaInfo()` if loading finished.
3. But how can I determine if loading is finished/in_progress? There is no `MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_*` for loading state. During loading `MediaStatus.getPlayerState()` returned `MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_IDLE`.

Comment: I still can't find answers. If I missed something in docs or other discussions please point me there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to determine the status of video loading after connection recovery as Default Receiver does not send something like MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_LOADING to the senders. See [state diagrams](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#events).

RemoteMediaPlayer does not update its state after connection recovery. In order to be in sync with receiver, call RemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(..) after connection recovery. Otherwise RemoteMediaPlayer may be in outdated state.